# How do I request a refresh token when using an iframe?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe

I am using React and do authentication with Keycloak.

I load independent pages from several pages into iframes.
The iframe child receives an access token from the parent when loaded to call the API (in App.tsx).

The problem is that if call the api when the access token has expired, receive a 401 response.
If a refresh token can be requested directly in the iframe, silent refresh will be performed through an axios interceptor.

However, the current structure requires requesting an access token and refresh token from the parent.

The method I came up with (referring to Googling) is to send and renew a refresh token request a few seconds before the expire time passes.

Q:
When making an axios request within an iframe, if a 401 response is received, is there a way to send a refresh token request to the parent, **wait for the response**, then pull out the failed request (like a silent refresh token using an Axios interceptor) and call it again?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing token refresh in an iframe involves communication between the iframe and its parent window. Here's a simplified step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

1. **Iframe Code**:
   In your iframe, when you receive a 401 response (token expired), trigger the token refresh process by sending a message to the parent window. You can use `window.parent.postMessage` for this.

   ```js
   // In the iframe
   const refreshTokenRequest = { action: 'refreshToken' };
   window.parent.postMessage(refreshTokenRequest, '*');
   ```
2. **Parent Window Code**:
   In the parent window, listen for the message from the iframe and handle the token refresh process.

   ```js
   // In the parent window
   window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
     if (event.data.action === 'refreshToken') {
       // Perform token refresh logic
       // Once the token is refreshed, send a response back to the iframe
       const newToken = 'newAccessToken'; // Replace with the refreshed token
       const tokenRefreshedResponse = { action: 'tokenRefreshed', newToken };
       event.source.postMessage(tokenRefreshedResponse, event.origin);
     }
   });
   ```
3. **Iframe Code (Retry Request)**:
   In the iframe, listen for the response from the parent window indicating that the token has been refreshed. When you receive the response, retry the original failed request with the new token.

   ```js
   // In the iframe
   window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
     if (event.data.action === 'tokenRefreshed') {
       // Retry the original failed request with the new token (event.data.newToken)
     }
   });
   ```

This communication flow allows the iframe to request a token refresh from the parent window, and once the parent window refreshes the token, it sends a response back to the iframe. The iframe can then use the new token to retry the original request.